# Will silicone spray lubricant cause bare dry wood to swell?

Tags: wood, lubrication, silicone

If wooden parts are binding, will silicone spray lubricant cause bare dry wood to swell?  The wood is not maple or oak or birch.  It is some type of softwood, maybe fir or pine.  The bearing surfaces are not painted or varnished, just bare wood.

Comment: Use Paste Wax. Silicone spray won't last long enough to be worth the bother. Bowling Alley Wax (just look in the wax section at the hardware store) is a particularly nice version, as it does not have the abrasives some other paste waxes do. A can may last you a lifetime if you don't lose it or buy a bowling alley. ;-)

Comment: needn't last to long

Answer (score 1):

A dry silicone spray lube is fine for bare wood applications. If you apply the spray to a cloth then wipe it on the binding surfaces, you should not have any problems with swelling. you can also use furniture polish, but in many cases, polish uses a silicone base as well with wax. Wax can build up, so I like pure silicon best.

As with any application to unfinished wood, test a small inconspicuous area to check for possible  discoloration if the surface is visible.

Comment: Visons of @Shirlock gluing tiny slices of pure silicon wafers to his drawer slides ;-) Does he get them new from the fab, or painstakingly recycle them from dead electronics? That "e" (more the lack of it) just drives me around the bend sometimes...

Comment: Without some creativity, I won't be able to wipe it on. Not worried about discoloration, but good point. I guess I'll apply in modest amounts to keep it to the minimum.  Thanks. (need more reps to upvote)

Comment: You should be fine Franklin.  don't worry about upvotes, I got more than I need.  lol  it's not about votes to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used silicon spray lube. 
But it should say what it's used for on the back of the container.

You didn't really say what the object is that's binding. More than likely, it's a drawer? 
Wax would be a very good alternative to use for your problem.

Why is it binding in the 1st place? 
It could be because the timber has moved since moisture in the air. Witch has made it to tight.

More than likely it is pine, since it's used in a lot of furniture.